# Spring Cloud Stream has automatic reconnection rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, cloud, spring-rabbit

I need reconnect rabbitmq after lost connection. I would like know if spring cloud stream has this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will automatically attempt to reconnect every 5 seconds, as long as you have a consumer binding.